# How I can clean Embedded Mongodb before each test class

Tags: maven, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am writing tests for my application by class and have order method to do a specific scenario for each class, if I test each class separately it's work perfect but when I run `mvn verfiy` only the first-class success and the others filled because all of them use the **same database** when maven run.

how I can clean the database or drop and re-create it for each class? or if I can re-init the spring context for each class and it can re-create the database.

lib: `SpirngBoot(2.3.0)`, `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo(2.2.0)`, `Junit5(5.5.2)`

Sample code of each class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class DefaultValuesTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var testData: TestDataInit

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var usersRepo: UsersRepo

    @BeforeAll
    fun init() {
        testData.init()
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    fun `check if init with default values`() {
        val users = usersRepo.findAll()
        Assertions.assertFalse(users.isNullOrEmpty())
    }
}
```

When every class start the method `testData.init()` the data exist before and some unique index throw errors.

Comment: Include this annotation in your class
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)